# Which entities should be included in the DbContext, only the base class or every derived classes?

Tags: entity-framework

**Album**, **Article**, and **Photo** are all derived classes of **Content**.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   //What set should be here ???!
}
```

I wonder whether only adding `public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }` is enough or need to represent all the entities like this?

```
public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: How do you wan't your database structure to look like?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, what do you mean by how do I want my database structure to like? I'm sorry, can u be more explicit.

Comment: Do you want to have a separate table for each derived entity or just one table, with all columns from all possible entities derived from `Content`?

Comment: I don't mind to have all of them in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a sample of how to set up your model, this is an example.
you can create classes that are mapped to the same table.

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext() : 
      base("ConnectioString")      // this is from the App.Config
   {
   }

   public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }

   [Table("Content")]   
   public class Content 
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int ContentId { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public bool Field { get; set; }
   }

   [Table("Content")]  
   public class Album 
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int ContentId { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public bool Field { get; set; }
   }
}
```